# Validating duplicate entries in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add the serial number in recycler view by using the add button.
need to check whether duplicate value trying to add in recycler view.

add button Onclick listener code are given below

```
 serialNumberAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!serialNumberField.getText().toString().equals("")) {

            // here need to check the duplicate values

                SerialNumberPojo serialNumberPojo = new SerialNumberPojo(serialNumberField.getText().toString());
                serialNumberPojoList.add(serialNumberPojo);

                RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.serial_recycle);
                serialNumberAdapter = new SerialNumberAdapter(serialNumberPojoList, view.getContext(), ScannedDetailsFragment.this);

                actualQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(serialNumberAdapter.getItemCount()));
                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(serialNumberAdapter);
                serialNumberAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



            } else {
                messageDialog.showAlertDialogBox(getContext(), "Add or Scan Serial Number", "error");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can check by `contains` or you can use `HashSet` list which prevent duplicate values.

Comment: serialNumberPojoList  has the custom datatype pojo class, I tried with contains but not work

Comment: You need to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` method in your pojo after that `contains` will work.

Comment: public boolean equals(Object obj) {


        return super.equals(obj);
    }

   
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }  I have implemented this in pojo class is that ok or need code on this methods

Comment: You need to implement actual code there, e. g.

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        SerialNumberPojo  that = (SerialNumberPojo) o;

        return !(getId() != null ? !getId().equals(that.getId()) : that.getId() != null);

    }

Comment: You have some problems in the logic of creating Recycle View.
Always after click on `serialNumberAddButton` you create a new instance of Recycle View. The variable `serialNumberPojo` always will contain one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SerialNumberPojo serialNumberPojo = new SerialNumberPojo(serialNumberField.getText().toString());
if (!serialNumberPojoList.contains(serialNumberPojo)) {
    serialNumberPojoList.add(serialNumberPojo);
}
```

And in SerialNumberPojo you need to implement your own equals() like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) return true;
    if (other == null || getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;

    SerialNumberPojo  that = (SerialNumberPojo) other;

    if (getId() != null && getId().equals(that.getId())) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can init Recycle View in `onCreate` function. Like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(...) {
    ...
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.serial_recycle);
    serialNumberAdapter = new SerialNumberAdapter(serialNumberPojoList, view.getContext(), ScannedDetailsFragment.this);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(serialNumberAdapter);
    ...
}
```

and in your `OnClickListener` check for dublicate as write @Szymon Chaber

```
serialNumberAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!serialNumberField.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            SerialNumberPojo serialNumberPojo = new SerialNumberPojo(serialNumberField.getText().toString());
            if (!serialNumberPojoList.contains(serialNumberPojo)) {
                serialNumberPojoList.add(serialNumberPojo);
            } else {
                // your action if found duplicate value 
            }
            serialNumberAdapter.updateData(serialNumberPojoList);
            serialNumberAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            actualQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(serialNumberAdapter.getItemCount()));
        } else {
            messageDialog.showAlertDialogBox(getContext(), "Add or Scan Serial Number", "error");
        }
    }
});
```